# Error: attempt to apply non-function in tbl_uvregression from gtsummary

Tags: gtsummary

when I attempt to use tbl_uvregression from the gtsummary package I keep getting an error message about attempting to apply a non-function.

Here is an example:

```
library(gtsummary)
library(tidyverse)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
# package 1.7.0

data("mtcars")

cars <- mtcars %>% 
    dplyr::select(mpg, disp, cyl, hp) %>% 
tbl_uvregression(
    method = "lm",
    y = hp,
    exponentiate = TRUE,
)

# Performing individual univariate linear regression works just fine
lm(hp ~ mpg, data = cars)
lm(hp ~ disp, data = cars)
lm(hp ~ cyl, data = cars)
```

I get the following error message:
There was an error constructing model `"lm"(formula = hp ~ mpg, data = .)` See error below.
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `model = map(...)`.
Caused by error in `value[[3L]]()`:
! Error in eval(.): attempt to apply non-function
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

> 

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

PS: I really enjoy using gtsummary, many thanks for creating this excellent package!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made two small changes.

1. Unquoted `method = lm`.
2. Change `exponentiate = FALSE` because `TRUE` is not  valid for `lm()` models.

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.7.0'

mtcars %>% 
  select(mpg, disp, cyl, hp) %>% 
  tbl_uvregression(
    method = lm,
    y = hp,
    exponentiate = FALSE, # TRUE is not valid for lm() models
  ) %>%
  as_kable() # convert to kable to display on stackoverflow
```

| **Characteristic** | **N** | **Beta** | **95% CI** | **p-value** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| mpg | 32 | -8.8 | -12, -6.2 | <0.001 |
| disp | 32 | 0.44 | 0.31, 0.56 | <0.001 |
| cyl | 32 | 32 | 24, 40 | <0.001 |

<sup>Created on 2023-02-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>